# Implode an array into a list of strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array:

```
$arr = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
```

How can I implode this into a string that looks like:

```
'item1', 'item2', 'item3'
```

Note the single quotes in above output are important. I realise I can do this using a `foreach` but am wondering if there is a more elegant way similar to `implode` and `join` that can do this in a single function. I can only seem to implode the array into a CSV list without the single quotes:

```
echo implode(',', $arr);
//outputs
item1, item2, item3
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the quotes to the implode call:

```
$Csv = "'" . implode("', '", $arr) . "'";
```